# How to change modem settings with Python Code

Tags: python, ip, python-requests, modem

When I change some parameter and turn it to correct value on DSL Configuration of Modem Settings, IP that I am using changes so I wanted to write a python code to login modem interface(192.168.1.1) and change some parameter on DSL Configuration. I am able to login but I can not post the port data but indeed the parameter does not change. The code that I am using is somewhat like below;

```
payload = {'Password': '1111', 'Username': 'admin','action':'login','LoginId':'Login'}
page = requests.post('http://192.168.1.1',data=payload)
payload ='?TypeUplink=1&pageType=0&IF_ACTION=Apply&_InstID=IGD.WD1.WCD2.WCPPP1&InstHasGot=1&ControlType=0&WANCName=ttt&xdslMode=2'       
page = requests.post('http://192.168.1.1/common_page/Internet_Internet_lua.lua'+payload)
```

My Modem is ZTE ZXHN H267N.

Comment: Are you really sure, that the data for the second request goes into the query string (aka GET parameters) and not into the POST-payload?

Comment: You might find it easier to use something like [mechanize](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize) to automate the browser activity. Or you can use the developer console in Chrome to capture the interaction so you can replicate it using requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try selenium on chrome or developer console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) for firefox to see what post/get requests you need. Possibly make sure that when sending your "parameters" after authentication that you are still logged in.